# Reloading an activerecord object in rspec updates the database record instead of reloading the object from the db

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am upgrading my app from Rails 4.0 to 4.1 (on my way to 4.2) and have tests like this that are failing:

```
describe "#restore_disabled_account" do
  let(:username) { 'username' }
  let(:email) { 'email@domain.com' }
  let(:m3_user) { create(:user, username: username,
                                   email: email,
                                archived: false,
                  propagate_in_test_mode: true) }
  let(:m2_user) { Maestro2::User.where(UserID: m3_user.id).first }

  before do
    m3_user.disable_account
  end

  it "unarchives the account" do
    m3_user.restore_disabled_account
    m3_user.reload
    expect(m3_user.archived).to be_falsey
  end
end
```

I have verified that the database contains a record with the expected attributes at the beginning of this test. When debugging the test and I stop before the reload statement, I see that the db record has been updated as expected (archived is false and other attributes are updated as expected). I can also see that the m3_user object has been updated with the same attributes. When I step forward to run the reload step and query the db, I can see the record has returned to its original state, as has the object in memory. The test then fails because m3_user.archived is true.

Can anybody tell me why? All tests in my suite were passing before starting the upgrade. The app is currently using Ruby 2.2.4, Rails 4.1.16, rspec 3.5.3 and rspec-rails 3.5.2

For reference, the two User class method calls are below:

```
def disable_account
  self.update_attributes(username: "disabled_#{id}_#{username}",
                            email: "disabled_#{id}_#{email}",
                         archived: true)
end

def restore_disabled_account
  self.update_attributes(username: username.gsub(/^disabled_#{id}_/, ''),
                            email: email.gsub(/^disabled_#{id}_/, ''),
                         archived: false)
end
```

Comment: this is unrelated to the question but `"#{username}"` is redundant. All you're interpolating is the variable itself, so it just needs to be `username: username` etc. Interpolation is for when the string contains more than just dynamic Ruby code.

Comment: also can you please add the contents of the `#restore_disabled_account` method and try removing the bang `!` from `let!`?

Comment: I've added the code you asked for. Removing the bang did not change the results unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. Just looking up some things online and found that `update_attributes` is deprecated (removed?) in 4.1: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html. Can you try changing the method to `update`? Also, stop again before the `reload` statement and call `valid?` on the object. The API docs say that `false` will be returend (so no Exception) if the object is invalid when it tries to save: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update

Comment: I hadn't noticed that deprecation yet. Changing update_attributes to update did not, however, change the results. I'll add one other note. When running this test, I've seen an UPDATE query run in the test.log which restores the original values when the m3_user.reload step is executed.

Comment: It turns out that ActiveRecord 4.1 changed the `reload` method to call a new private method called `reset_changes`. My User class also had a `reset_changes` method so my method overrode what should have been called. I've changed it to `undo_changes` and my specs are green. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Definitely add that as an answer! Tricky one

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: It turns out that ActiveRecord 4.1 changed the `reload` method to call a new private method called `reset_changes`. My User class also had a `reset_changes` method so my method overrode what should have been called.

The long answer: The more I looked at this, the more I suspected something unique to my User model. Other tests using `reload` performed as expected. I then came across a `reset_changes` method in User. After seeing what it did (update the db record with the previous values), I dropped a puts statement into it so I would see if it was called. Once that was confirmed, I dumped the caller backtrace which pointed me to https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb#L37

I've changed my User model method to `undo_changes` and my specs are green.